# CodeIgniter: insert_batch from Custom Library - Fails with no Return or Error - How to Debug?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, batch-insert

I have a custom CodeIgniter library where I need to run a few database operations.

To get access to the database, I perform this command, which I learned here on StackOverflow:

```
$this->CI =& get_instance();
```

I know it's working, since this command works:

```
$drop_query = "DELETE FROM product_images WHERE product_id = " .  $this->CI->db->escape($product_id);
$this->CI->db->query($drop_query);  // Tested, this works.
```

However, **insert_batch** does not work at all.  No FALSE returned, no errors... nothin.  It just dies.

```
    $master_insert_array = array(
        array(
            'product_id' => $product_id,
            'thumb_type' => 'original',
            'filename' => $orig_file_name
        ),
        array(
            'product_id' => $product_id,
            'thumb_type' => 'small',
            'filename' => $small_file_name
        ) // Truncating the rest of this...
    );

    error_log("update_product_image_db: Insert_Batch Coming up:");

    $batch_success = $this->CI->db->insert_batch('product_images', $master_insert_array);
    error_log("\n\n".$this->CI->db->last_query()."\n");
```

*EDIT:  It turns out that my $product_id was failing foreign key constraints, making the batch_insert fail.*

The second error_log never gets run after it fails.  The script just dies.

So how can I get insert_batch to properly return me a FALSE, an error, or something other than flat out fails?

*UPDATE: I've also tried putting this into a try/catch block, with no success.  If it fails foreign key constraint, it aborts my entire script.  It is of my current opinion that insert_batch is a poorly-written function*

Thanks!

Comment: Use `echo $this->db->last_query()` just before the last `error_log` and see the output.

Comment: That didn't work, but it turns out, my $product_id WAS failing foreign key constraints.   SO this was a bum query.  Sorry about that.

Going to update this post in a second.  I think the REAL question is, how to properly call insert_batch and get a FALSE/Error returned...

Comment: Wow, 1.5 months later and this strip of code is still haunting me.  If only I could get an error back from this thing... or an exception... or anything but a dead crash.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but Codeigniter still has this problem in v. 2, so hopefully this will help someone.

For whatever reason, `insert_batch()` doesn't return the same way as a standard query.  Generally, you could just do this:

```
if(!$this->CI->db->insert('product_images', $simpleArray)
{
    error_log("\n\n".$this->CI->db->last_query()."\n");
}
```

But as discovered in the original question, insert_batch won't return false on a failed query.  For `insert_batch()`, this workaround has nicely solved the problem in my applications:

```
$this->CI->db->insert_batch('product_images', $master_insert_array);

if($this->CI->db->_error_message() != '')
{
    error_log("\n\n".$this->CI->db->last_query()."\n");
}
```